# Maximum values for frequency and amplitude in Qiskit pulses on IBM devices

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

Where can I find information about the maximum frequency and maximum amplitude for Qiskit pulses on various IBM quantum computers?

Note: it looks like information about frequency range can be found in this paper at page 32: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03452.pdf. I don't know where to find some info about the maximum pulse amplitude.